# Unable to return resolve in promise function inside module.exports

Tags: node.js

I am trying to return resolve() from module.exports promise function.
I am calling it like this:

```
prog
  .version('1.0.0')
  .command('addpeer')
  .argument('<pubkey>', 'Enter the pubkey (pubkey@address)')
  .action((args, options, logger) => {
        return addPeers({
          logger,
          pubkey: args.pubkey,
          lnd: lnd,
        },
        );
  })
```

From there it goes another file where all module.exports are defined:
It finds which file to go to from here. I am calling the addPeers file.

```
const importLazy = require('import-lazy')(require);
const listPeers = importLazy('./listPeers.js');
const addPeers = importLazy('./addPeer.js')
const getChannels = importLazy('./getChannels.js')
const openChannels = importLazy('./openChannel.js');
const lnurl = importLazy("./lnurl");
const AddPeer_OpenChannel = importLazy('./AddPeer_OpenChannel.js');

module.exports = {
  lnurl,
  listPeers,
  addPeers,
  getChannels,
  openChannels,
  AddPeer_OpenChannel
};
```

From there it comes here, now i am not understanding how to return Resolve here, I am able to return reject but not return resolve.

```
module.exports = args  => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    if (!args.pubkey) {
      return reject(new Error('404-ExpectedPubKey'));
    }
    
    if (!args.lnd) {
      return reject(new Error('404-ExpectedLndAuthentication'));
    }
    args.logger.info("inside this");
    const lnd = args.lnd;
    const id = args.pubkey;
    const str = id.split('@');
    const pubKey = str[0];
    const address = str[1];

    lnService.addPeer({ lnd, public_key: pubKey, socket: address }, (err, result) => {
      if(err)
      reject(err);
      else
      resolve(result);
  });


    return resolve();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't "return" from a promise callback. You call resolve() or reject(), you don't do `return resolve()`. Just `resolve()`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `callback` is executed and use only `resolve`. Below is the sample snippet:

```
class SampleClass {
    add(a, b, cb) {
        a + b;
        cb();
    }
}
const obj = new SampleClass();

module.exports = args => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        if (!args.pubkey) {
            reject(new Error('404-ExpectedPubKey'));
        }

        if (!args.lnd) {
            reject(new Error('404-ExpectedLndAuthentication'));
        }
        console.info("inside this");
        obj.add(1, 2, (err,res)=>{
            if(err) reject(err)
            resolve(`Resolved: ${res}`)
        })
    });
};
```